# Is there any way to know the Salesforce edition when an app is installed via the App Exchange?

Tags: isv, group-edition, professional-edition, enterprise

We are a Salesforce ISV and see many leads from the App Exchange. SF-IN is a click on "Try it Now".. "SF-Installation" is a completed installation. We have no way to know if the drop off from "try it now" to a completed installation is due to Professional Edition or Group Edition, which we do not support. Is there any way we can know what edition an app exchange lead is on?

And a related question -- are PE and GE orgs the majority or minority for Salesforce?

Comment: FWIW, GE and CE are virtually useless, and so there may be a bunch of them, but almost nobody in that group of buyers are going to be using paid apps because they are already on a tight budget. PE is a starting type of database, most organizations outgrow it in a few years, tops. In other words, EE is the dominant type, with some of the ultra-large accounts on UE. If your app is useful to small groups, you may need to be PE-capable. Being an ISV managed app will let you run in GE/PE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no. I think that once the app is installed you do have that info, but that's not useful to you :) The answer to your second question isn't as easy. It depends on what your app does, who you're targetting and the cost. From my experience (I'm part of one of the largest salesforce consultancies in Europe) most Orgs are EE.

If possible you should apply for [Aloha status](http://blogs.developerforce.com/systems-integrator/2010/04/design-an-aloha-app.html), that might let PE and GE orgs install your app.

Comment: Wes - do you happen to know of a way to access "Subscribers" via a report? SFDC gives us the org type for "Subscribes" but I cannot seem to find a way to create a report, or even a View the the data?

Comment: There is no report. The object that stores this data is called `AllPackage`, and it is a private standard object that is not describable, queryable, or reportable.